# Segue will not load using performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, xcode, segue

I have given my segue the identity modaltomenu

[image: modaltomenu]

in my code I am calling the segue with the following:

```
if([login_status isEqualToString:@"success"]){
            //start the menuviewcontroller
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modaltomenu" sender:self];

            NSLog(@"segue %@", @"performed");
        }
```

the if statement is always true.

However the second view is never loaded. This code is ran when the first view loads.

Why isnt my segue loading?

Thanks!

Comment: First check that you have your segue properly hooked up from one view controller to the other. Implement prepareForSegue and see if it's getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said the code is ran when the first view loads so am I right in assuming its in the viewDidLoad method? If so, try moving that if statement to the viewDidAppear method in the view controller life cycle. ViewDidLoad usually only happens once, whereas viewDidAppear is called every time the view appears on screen. So it would look like...

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    if([login_status isEqualToString:@"success"]){
        //start the menuviewcontroller
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modaltomenu" sender:self];

        NSLog(@"segue %@", @"performed");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the case, You can't segue to another view in ViewDidLoad.  You can't perform a segue until the View has Appeared.

Comment: This worked. Your sir are legendary. More legendary than an articuno. <3.

Comment: and Upped to justin on justification xx.

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot further, put this in that VC:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"segue identififer = %@",segue.identifier);
}
```

And make sure that your code in `viewDidLoad` is executing as expected.  If it doesn't, you might want to re-think where you call that `performSegue` method.

Comment: Can't perform a segue in `viewDidLoad`.  View has to appear first.

Comment: it is being called. But this helped me to debug and will help me in future. Yty sir!